# Proof the function is harmonic without differetiation

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

How to prove that 
$$
f(x,y)=\cos(\cos(x)\cosh(y))\cosh(\sin(x)\sinh(y))
$$ is harmonic?

What properties of harmonic functions are useful here?

I can express 
\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=1/2 (\cos(\cos(x) \cosh(y) - i \sin(x) \sinh(y)) + \cos(\cos(x) \cosh(y) + i \sin(x) \sinh(y)))\\
&=1/2(\cos(\cos(x+iy))+\cos(\cos(x-iy))\;,
\end{align} 
is there a way to proceed from here?

Comment: Real and imaginary parts of holomorphic functions are harmonic. With some algebra you may be able to recognize $f$ as something of this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that $\cosh{t}=\cos{it}$, and $\sinh{t}=i\sin{-it}$ so that $2f(x,y)=\cos(\cos{x}\cos{iy}-i\sin{x}i\sin{iy})+\cos(\cos{x}\cos{iy}+i\sin{x}i\sin{iy})=\cos{\cos(x-iy)}+\cos{\cos(x+iy)}$ is the sum of a holomorphic and a anti-holomorphic function, so is harmonic.